# How to export the coredata with relationships to a CSV

Tags: ios, csv, export-to-csv

How to export the coredata with relationships to a CSV and how to retain the relationship while importing

Comment: CoreData is just a wrapper around DB (most probably used one is SQLite). You have to write your own code to convert it to CSV and use in the app or export it to CSV and use in other environment.

Comment: what is your question exactly? read this article to ask better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are highly encouraged to use a more reliable format like JSON or Property List rather than CSV. With `Codable` you can put the serialization code directly into the `NSManagedObject` subclasses.